# Wrong Document getting added to MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been beating my head around this code but I am unable to figure out the solution to the problem that I am facing.

I have the following schema for the mongoDb document.

```
{

    "brand" : "String",
    "series" : "String",
    "model" : "String",
    "deviceType" : "String",
    "progress" : "Number",
    "uploaded" : []

}
```

Following is the function that i am using for adding the document to the  database

```
var addData = function(details){
    console.log(details);
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var document = new Document({

            brand : details.brand,
            series : details.series,
            model : details.model,
            devicetype : details.devicetype,
            progress : 0,
            uploaded : []

        });

    //save the document into the database
    document.save(function(err, document){
        if(err){
            reject(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log('document added--' + document);
            console.log('document should be--' + details);
            resolve('Document added successfully');
        }

    });

})
return promise; 
}
```

The details object that I am using to populate the document is coming out as follows

```
{ brand: 'HP',
  series: 'Elitebook',
  model: '8460P',
  devicetype: 'laptop',
  progress: 0,
  uploaded: [] }
```

But the document that is getting added is not as per the schema and one of the fields is missing in the document. Could some one please tell where I am going wrong. Following is the document that is getting added.

```
document added--{ __v: 0,
  brand: 'HP',
  series: 'Elitebook',
  model: '8460P',
  progress: 0,
  _id: 5850f50f0a0d7f055c441b7c,
  uploaded: [] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `_id` is the MongoDB ID that is added to every document so that it can be referenced.
- [`__v`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey) is added by Mongoose for versioning of the document.
- `devicetype` is not added to the document as it is not in your model. You added `deviceType`, not `devicetype`. These property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend